# Removing formatting elements to default - Reducing file size

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to remove specific formatting from some cells in excel but I have a specific need to not use `.ClearFormats` as I need to retain other formatting.

For example, if I have used the `.Borders.LineStyle` property previously and want to clear the borders I can use `.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone` which works visually to remove borders. However, this method seems to leave  an allocation of data for the formatting attributes of the cells in the file size (undesirable).

I run this

```
Sub allBorders()

 With ActiveSheet
   dim rng as Range : set rng = .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(5000,5000))
   rng.Borders.xlLineStyle = xlContinuous
 End With

End Sub
```

and save the file, I get a 65MB file. That's OK

If I then clear formats with `rng.clearformats` and re-save, the file size returns to ~16kB as expected.

But if, instead of clearFormats, I do:

```
Sub clearAllBorders()

 With ActiveSheet
   dim rng as Range : set rng = .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(5000,5000))
   rng.Borders.xlLineStyle = xlNone
 End With

End Sub
```

then save, the file size remains large at 65MB.

I want to only remove the specific formatting and release the allocated data in the file if no other formatting exists for those cells.

---

Further information if interested why:
I don't want to use `.clearFormats`, as there are other formats in the range that I wish to keep. I only wish to remove specific formatting and if any cells in the range have no other formatting then to have the unnecessary file space by having no formatting, released.

Due to the large range of cells, I do not want to do attribute by attribute and cell by cell checking for individual formatting combinations before then using clearFormats on individual cells to get the released space back. (slow)

It is also not possible to `.clearFormats` and reformat the desired formats (very complex & slow)

Once a cell is formatted in someway, the only way to release the space seems to be with `.clearFormats`

Is there a flag or cell attribute that needs to be set, or is set by `.clearFormats`, that I can manipulate directly to tell excel to release the space?

Comment: Wow! 16Kb vs 65Mb?? That's a huge difference!? Are you allowed/able to clear it all and then reapply? What about using styles? Have you played with applying styles to see if that helps?

Comment: I am allowed to do anything but I cannot reapply. It would need a huge amount of rework and additional macros to reformat the parts I wanted to keep.

Comment: Even applying .Borders.LineStyle = xlNone without any previous formatting will allocate file space for formatting. It certainly seems like a flag is being set somewhere.

Comment: I think you have to loop the specified range.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid @Waleed. That would take too long for this application/data size (~10M cells)

Comment: One suggestion (which may not help with file size): if you want to work with all the cells on a sheet use `UsedRange` ... that gives a square range that includes all the cells (and no more) that have data or formatting. If you set the format on a cell you aren't using, Excel will still use memory for that cell.

Comment: The difference is likely due to the difference between nothing and adding a structure that describes the format of a cell, when it differs from the default.  Setting a formatting different to the default  likely adds an structurewhich has fields for all formatting parameters.  Changing one of the parameters doesn't change the need for this object.  Resetting all parameters may allow the object to be removed.  Hence the behaviour you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a non-default formatting for a mix of used & unused 5000x5000 cells while trying to remove the border formatting.

Excel saves a small info for "each cell" which has non-default formatting. This small formatting information (required by OfficeOpenXML format specifications) can take more space compared to the content of the cell.

Instead, try only removing the borders in the UsedRange. Or, try to reset the UsedRange. Or remove the trailing empty rows and columns after finishing the formatting, which will reset the UsedRange when you save the file.

You can check the LastCell that Excel thinks is used by pressing CTRL+END in a worksheet. This is usually the boundary of the UsedRange.